# Question about derivative of $\overline{f}$ with respect to z

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading Ahlfors' complex analysis (third edition), and come up to this question.

It said on P27 that the conjugate function $\overline{f(z)}$ has the derivative zero with respect to z.

I don't understand if $\overline{f(z)}$ has derivative (similar to when the derivative of f exists), then the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\overline{f(z+h)}-\overline{f(z)}}{h}$ exists, then the limit exists along real axis and along imaginary axis.

Then $\overline{f(z)}'=\frac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial x}$
and $\overline{f(z)}'=\lim_{k\to 0}=\frac{\overline{f(z+ik)}-\overline{f(z)}}{ik}=-i\frac{\partial \overline {f}}{\partial y}$

[image]
[image]

Then follow the similar formal procedure of f

[image]
Then follow the similar formal procedure of f.
Then wouldn't be $\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{z}}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{x}}-i\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{y}}\right)$ and $\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{\overline{z}}}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{x}}+i\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{y}}\right)$

So $\frac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial\overline{z}}=0$, but this is clearly wrong.

Comment: If $f$ has a derivative at $z$, then Cauchy Riemann's equations are satisfied at z. Therefore,  $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\bar z}}=0.$

Comment: $\frac{\partial{\bar z}}{\partial {\bar z}}=1/2(1+i \cdot (-i))=1$, so you are making some mistake.

Comment: It means the latter: derivative of $\bar f$ w.r.t. $z$ is $0$ (this follows by taking conjugate of  $\frac{\partial{ f}}{\partial{\bar z}}=0).$ So $\bar f$ can be treated as a function of $\bar z$.

Comment: No, the partial derivative by $z$ equaling zero doesn’t make it constant, just like the partial derivative by x doesn’t make a function constant - it just means along certain directions in the $x,y$ plane the function is constant.

Comment: @Eric, yes there definitely exists mistakes, but I can not see where the mistakes are

Comment: @koro, thanks but I think what I don't understand is how to find $\frac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial\overline{z}}, \frac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial{z}}$ following the specific formal procedure given in the book.

Comment: I don’t really get why you’re confused - i showed you explicitly with $\bar z$ how to use the definition in the book to get a nonzero result. Your proof is just stating some true things and then stating the thing you care about is 0. Plug in $\bar z$ and see how  it’s not actually 0.  The formal definitions here are just the sums of the partial derivatives wrt x and y, as you’ve noted.